# The following requested languages could not be built: c++ (LINUX, GCC)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm trying to configure my GCC installation (because I have no root) as it mentioned in this tutorial [here](http://luiarthur.github.io/gccinstall)

Snippet from tutorial:

```
tar xzf gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-5.2.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-5.2.0 
make
make install
```

At the step with "configure" I get this error:

```
configure: error: bootstrapping requires c++ sources
```

So I tried to enable c++ resources with this line:

```
../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/kunden/homepages/43/d632761372/htdocs/Plugins/apps/  --enable-languages=c++
```

And after that i'm getting this error:

```
The following requested languages could not be built: c++ Supported languages are: c,java
```

So it seems I dont have c++ installed? But I need it.

I'm very noob to linux (Debian) so please help me out here. 
(Working with PuTTY and SSH Connection)

Comment: can you access apt-get install commands? (I no you are not root, but maybe it is available for you)

Comment: nope. sadly not I already tried it. Thats why I use this tutorial because I cant install things normally with apt-get and so on.

Comment: so, the issue you are gettng is the following: gcc compiler is a C/C++ compiler written in C/C++ ... so it needs an older version of a compiler, to compile itself. You are missing a compiler right from the beginning (g++) which is required to compile gcc ... so to bootstrap it , Sadly I do not how to fix it, but maybe this helps you to look for a solution

Answer (score 0):

From [GCC's libgo folder](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libgo):

> This library is intended for use with the Go frontend.